# Error with xassoccnt - LaTeX3 \c_one deprecated

Tags: latex3, xassoccnt

Package `xassoccnt` seems to be causing a \LaTeX3 error as of now, as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article} % same error with memoir

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
% not used in this test document, but seems to cause error
% (it's used int the "real" document, together with zref ,
%  to allow reference to the part of a section number after decimal point) 

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

The log includes:

```
./test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use 1 not \c_one deprecated on 2020-01-01.
l.10     \end{document}
```

And indeed, `xassoccnt.sty` (version 1.7, dated 2018/12/28), does use `\c_one` several times (as well as `c_zero`.

I have not encountered this error with `xassoccnt` a day or two ago, and it seems that the package has not changed recently, so the cause seems to be something very recently updated in LaTeX/LaTeX3.

The error seems to be independent of the documentclass (same thing with `book` or `memoir`). It occurs no matter whether pdflatex or xelatex is used.

What is a fix here?

Here's a longer selection from the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.18)  18 JUL 2020 11:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xassoccnt/xassoccnt.sty
Package: xassoccnt 2018/12/28 - v1.7

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/07/15 v2.5i e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count176
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-07-17 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-29 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count177
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
))
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.
tex
...)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2020-05-15 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
...
Package xassoccnt Info: 2018/12/28-v1.7--steppingcounterssimultaneouslyandother
features on input line 7.
...
{/Users/me/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
./test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Use 1 not \c_one deprecated on 2020-01-01.
l.10     \end{document}
```

Comment: The correct fix™ is to contact the maintainer of `xassoccnt` and ask them to update their package (contact details are usually on CTAN). (But maybe there is a clever workaround to get the document to compile again. I can't investigate further, because my `expl3` version is a tad older than yours and doesn't seem to have the deprecations active yet.)

Comment: In case the author does not respond, picking up maintenance of the package and submitting fixed versions to CTAN are going to be a hassle, because the package is `author-maintained`.

Comment: The email address given at CTAN in the docs for the package's author/maintainer, Dr. Christian Hupfer, does not work! Anybody know how else to contact him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in comments, the correct 'fix' is for the package to be updated (more below). As an *urgent* repair, one can do

```latex
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \c_one
\int_const:Nn \c_one { 1 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

before loading `xassoccnt`.

---

In general, packages using `expl3` are expected to be updated periodically as the language evolves: this is made clear in the *broadly* stable nature of the distribution and deprecation information. In the case of `xassoccnt`, there are two issues

- The package author has withdrawn from both package maintenance and more widely from
  social media
- The package is author-mainatained

A solution to these will be found, but it may not be immediate.

Comment: that fixes things for now with my MWE as well as the "real" book-length document, thanks.